# Date.today.to_s(:long) not converting to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am working on an assignment and I have written the following method based on our instructions:

```
def create_todolist(params)
    due_date = Date.today.to_s(:long)
    TodoList.create(list_name: params[:name],list_due_date: params[:due_date])
end
```

But when I run the rspec test, I get the following error:

```
1) Assignment rq03 rq03.2 assignment code has create_todolist method should create_todolist with provided parameters
     Failure/Error: expect(testList.list_due_date).to eq due_date

       expected: Thu, 07 May 2020
            got: "2020-05-07"

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -Thu, 07 May 2020
       +"2020-05-07"

     # ./spec/assignment_spec.rb:177:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/assignment_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the rspec test:

```
context "rq03.2 assignment code has create_todolist method" do
        it { is_expected.to respond_to(:create_todolist) } 
        it "should create_todolist with provided parameters" do
            expect(TodoList.find_by list_name: "mylist").to be_nil
            due_date=Date.today
            assignment.create_todolist(:name=> 'mylist', :due_date=>due_date)
            testList = TodoList.find_by list_name: 'mylist'
            expect(testList.id).not_to be_nil
            expect(testList.list_name).to eq "mylist"
            expect(testList.list_due_date).to eq due_date
            expect(testList.created_at).not_to be_nil
            expect(testList.updated_at).not_to be_nil
        end  
      end
```

At first I had just `due_date = Date.today` and was getting the same error and I'm not sure how to fix it. I'm wondering if it is because I am using a different version of ruby/rails than what was used when the course was created ( 5 years ago -_-).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you :)

Comment: Your question is unclear because you did not show what your test actually does. But something that already caught my eye: You assign `Date.today.to_s(:long)` to the local variabel `due_date` but never read from that variable anymore.

Comment: sorry, I've added it now

Comment: `params[:due_date]` is not using `due_date`.  They are two different variables.  Also, it said `expected: Thu, 07 May 2020 - got: "2020-05-07` maybe you need to convert it manually?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare a Date object:

```
due_date = Date.today
```

With a string object you generated while you created your record:

```
Date.today.to_s(:long)
```

As you can see, these are different types of objects:

```
Date.today.to_s(:long)
=> "May 07, 2020"
Date.today.to_s(:long).class
=> String

Date.today
=> 2020-05-07
Date.today.class
=> Date

Date.today.to_s(:long) == Date.today
=> false
```

Comment: Hello, I originally had just ``` Date.today ```  but getting the same error with that as well.

Comment: It is not likely it was the exact same error because you were dealing with a different type of object. Can you change back to Date.today and add here the exact error message you get?

Comment: Hi, I figured it out! when I was creating the TodoLists table, I didn't specify the migration type as :date. so by default, due_date was set to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When I was creating the TodoLists table, I didn't specify the migration type as :date. so by default, due_date was set to be a string. So I set to type :date and changed due_date to equal:

```
due_date = Date.today
```

Thank you for taking the time to help me out :)